# What happens if shutdown command kills my unison cron job?

Tags: linux, shutdown, cron, unison

I have an Arch linux box at home that I power off quite frequently (the power supply is noisy and it annoys my girlfriend...!).

The box has a number of [`cron`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) jobs running the [`unison`](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/) utility, designed to back up various directories onto external hard drives.

Since these jobs run by way of the `cron` daemon, in the background, it seems to me quite likely that I'll inadvertently run `$ shutdown now` while one of the backups is running.

What happens?

1. Will the `unison` job get killed immediately?
2. Is this likely to put Unison's metadata into a corrupt state?

Comment: The `shutdown` command sends SIGTERM to all processes. They have about 10 seconds time to cleanup their business. The next signal is SIGKILL, which terminates all other processes at once.

Comment: You'd be well-advised to invest in a machine with a quieter (preferably silent) power supply (or power supply and all other parts you'd hear with a silent power supply.) Don't let your computer annoy your girlfriend. ;^)

Comment: Not wanting to discourage you (I love Unison!), but do you really need two-way synchronization? From this description I'd guess a one-way (e.g., rsync) backup might be sufficient? There is a very nice answer over at Unix & Linux SE that deals with rsync and interruptions (http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/165417/65370).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short:

- powering off the machine stops any job **now**.
- Unison's [page](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/) states that

  > Unison is resilient to failure. It is careful to leave the replicas and its own private structures in a sensible state at all times, even in case of abnormal termination or communication failures.

Answer (score 1):

As Thomas Dickey already indicated, and from my own experience, Unison handles unexpected terminations, connection loss, etc., gracefully. Moreover, I've noticed that on the *next* synchronization, it will even pick up where it left off last time, saving you at least some bandwidth and/or time :)